# Total output of multiple carriers in a SMF

Tags: fiber-optics

If I have for instance 5 carriers, each of the individual carriers with 6dBm in a SMF with a core of 9 µm, is it valid to say that the total optical power launched in the fiber is of 6*5=30dBm?

Comment: Please explain your difficulty. Questions which ask for Yes or No answers are not suitable for this site.

Comment: @sammygerbil I don't know how to calculate the total input power in the fiber.

Comment: Have you tried converting to mW, calculating total power, then converting back to dBm?

Comment: @sammygerbil, I just realized it, thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

No, I can't!

For example, say some power P1 = 6 dBm is combined with power P2 = 10 dBm. What is the resulting total power?

If i sum up the P1 + P2= 16 dBm

However, P1 =  10 mW and P2 = 4 mW

So: Ptotal = 14 mW = 10*log10(14/1m) = 11.46 dBm and not 30dBm